# Yii select2 specific data

Tags: php, mysql, yii, jquery-select2

I have to make a webapp in Yii framework.

I want to work with select2 And want to use a column in my database..

This is my code

```html
<?php

$users= User::model()->findAll(array(

               'select'=>'name',


      ));
  

echo CHtml::textField('User','',array('id'=>'user', 'style'=>'width:300px;'));
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'selector'=>'#user',
  'options' => array(
  'tags'=> $names,
 
 
),
));

?>
```

When I use `vardump` to check what is in the variable $users then I get this:

Array
(
    [0] => User Object
        (
            [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [name] => "asd"
                )

```
        [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
        [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 
        [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
        [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_validators:CModel:private] => 
        [_scenario:CModel:private] => update
        [_e:CComponent:private] => 
        [_m:CComponent:private] => 
    )

[1] => User Object
    (
        [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
        [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [name] => "assss"
            )

        [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
        [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 
        [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
        [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_validators:CModel:private] => 
        [_scenario:CModel:private] => update
        [_e:CComponent:private] => 
        [_m:CComponent:private] => 
    )
```

And a lot more.

But the only thing I want is this:  `[name] => "assss" .`

I think I have too use an foreach loop or something like that because select2 wants a "clear" array.
Do you guys know how to do this?

Comment: sorry! I mean print_r not vardump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get array

```
   $array = CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), 'user_id', 'user_name');
```

Comment: when I use that code I get the last string in my database, but I want them all!

Comment: Replace with $users and add above code and print what you r getting the result?

Comment: if  I use vardump : array (size=1)
  '' => string 'tim' (length=3)

Comment: use print_r($array) function

Comment: then I got: Array
(
    [] => tim
)

Comment: Can you post your database queries create and insert in your main question ? so i will test at my end

Answer (score 0):

For example the following code

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'country', CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'), array('id' => 'country_list', 'multiple' => true)) ?>
<?php $this->widget('application.extensions.select2.ESelect2',
array(
    'selector' => "#country_list",
    'options' => array(
        'dropdownCssClass' => 'bigdrop',
        'width' => '60%',
    )
))?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

$users= User::model()->findAll(array(

               'select'=>'name',


      ));
  

echo CHtml::textField('User','',array('id'=>'user', 'style'=>'width:300px;'));
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'selector'=>'#user',
  'options' => array(
  'tags'=> $names,
 
 
),
));

?>
```